# Every orthonormal set in a Hilbert space is contained in some complete orthonormal set.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Show that every orthonormal set in $H$ is contained in some complete orthonormal set.

I'm unable to start from any direction. Do I use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to construct a complete orthonormal set that contains a chosen orthonormal set?

Comment: Do you know Zorn's lemma?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with it. How do I use it here?

Comment: Take the orthonormal sets containing your original one ordered by inclusion. Every chain is bounded above. Look then at the maximal element.

Comment: Would the maximal element be a complete orthonormal set?

Comment: Yes the maximal element is a complete orthonormal set.

Comment: If an orthonormal set were not complete, then it couldn't be "maximal" in the sense of set inclusions because then we could add another element to the orthonormal set to get something further up the chain

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have what I need. Could you post your comments as an answer?

Comment: I did it. Not a great math value, but will enable to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

*You need to use Zorn's lemma.*

Take the orthonormal sets containing your original one ordered by inclusion. Every chain is bounded above. Look then at the maximal element. You can prove that it is complete.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $D$ is your orthonormal set. You can define $$M = \overline{\mathrm{span}\, D}$$ so that $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$ and finite linear combinations of elements in $D$ are dense in $M$. That is, $D$ is a complete orthonormal set in $M$. Now write $$H = M \oplus M^\perp$$ and let $D'$ be a complete orthonormal set in $M^\perp$. You will need the axiom of choice for this, in general. Then $D \cup D'$ is the set you are looking for.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how the Axiom of choice being used here? I'm not completely clear.

Comment: It is appealing to the statement "every Hilbert space contains a complete orthonormal set". This requires the axiom of choice to prove.